# Freehand editing without holding down mouse button in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, digitizing

I am trying to delineate wetlands using satellite imagery in QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa.

I'm using the Freehand Editing plugin.

Is there a way to draw polygons without having to hold down the mouse button, like you can with the freehand tool in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such setting, but you could open a feature request on the plugin's bug tracker asking for this option.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the mouse button to a keyboard button using X-Mouse Button Control

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the above suggestion yet, but you can create lines in Google Earth by holding down the  mouse button (works pretty decent with a touchscreen too!) then save as kml/kmz and import into QGIS that way. It has its limitations but it's a quick fix.

Edit: Apparently I misread the original question, but I'm leaving my suggestion up because it might help somebody somewhere at some time.